# Having trouble transfering list values to sqlite from c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, list

**BG info:** Beginer Creating a desktop application which reads values from the columns in textfiles and then parses through them. I've managed to store every value from the textfile into 3 lists (3 lists because each list represents a section of the file).
I now plan to load these list values into an sqlite db. This is where the problem comes in.

**Errror Message**:
 ***"near "[i]" syntax error"*** happens in the sqlite part of the code when I try to transfer the list values. Specifically speaking, this part (It is located as the third part in the code segments below)

```
 sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 (Seq, Field, Description) VALUES (list[i], list[i+1], list[i+2]);";
```

**Code Leading up to the important parts**: *(This isn't important, just there for bg info in anyone needs it, I've highlited the important code segments below)*

```
 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] val = new string[10];
    string[] val2 = new string[6];
    string[] val3 = new string[7];
    string[] values = new string[1000];
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
    List<string> list3 = new List<string>();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Reading/Inputing column values



        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {

            // Data Reading from section 1.

            /*string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName).Skip(8).ToArray();
            textBox1.Lines = lines;
            */

            string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);

            // Import table values from Section 1: from Seq# to YYYY-MM

            string[] section1 = fileLines.SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("Seq#")).TakeWhile(line => !line.Contains("Total Records")).Where(line => Regex.IsMatch(line, @"[\s|\d]{4}\d")).Select(line => line.PadRight(198)).ToArray();


            int[] pos = new int[10] { 0, 6, 18, 47, 53,57, 61, 68, 82, 97 }; //setlen&pos to read specific colmn vals
            int[] len = new int[10] { 6, 12, 29, 6 , 4, 4, 7, 14, 15, 6 }; // only doing 3 columns right now
```

**Simply populating the list with column values:(This part works fine)**

```
            foreach (string line in section1)
            {
                //if (line.StartsWith("0")) break; 


                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) // 3 columns
                {
                    val[j] = line.Substring(pos[j], len[j]).Trim(); // each column value in row add to array
                    list.Add(val[j]); // column values stored in list

                }

            }
```

Important Part: SQLite connection (error happens here)**

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // [snip] - As C# is purely object-oriented the following lines must be put into a class:

        // We use these three SQLite objects:
        SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
        SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;


        // create a new database connection:
        sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;");

        // open the connection:
        sqlite_conn.Open();

        // create a new SQL command:
        sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();

        // Let the SQLiteCommand object know our SQL-Query:
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE table1 (Seq integer primary key, Field integer , Description integer );";

        // Now lets execute the SQL ;D                                                                                  
        sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i+=3)
        {
            // Lets insert something into our new table:
            sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 (Seq, Field, Description) VALUES (list[i], list[i+1], list[i+2]);"; THIS IS WHERE PROBLEM OCCURS!

            // And execute this again ;D
            sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        }

        // We are ready, now lets cleanup and close our connection:
        sqlite_conn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass your variables embedding them inside the sql string.
In this way they becomes literals and cannot work as values for integer fields.
You need to use a parameterized query

```
sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 (Seq, Field, Description) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)";
sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", 0);  // dummy initial values 
sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", 0);
sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", 0);
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i+=3)
{
    sqlite_cmd.Parameters["@p1"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(list[i]);
    sqlite_cmd.Parameters["@p2"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(list[i+1]);
    sqlite_cmd.Parameters["@p3"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(list[i+2]); // Description as Integer ??
    sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

In this code, the placeholders @p1, @p2 and @p3 represents the parameters that will be replaced by the appropriate value inside the loop. Before entering the loop the command parameters collection will be initialized with three parameters corresponding to the three placeholders and with a dummy initial value. Inside the loop every parameter receive the actual value to insert from your list variable.

Said that, you have other problems in your code above.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) // 3 columns
```

this line loop for 10 items not for 9 (0 to 9 are 10 elements)

The variable `list` used to feed the parameters for inserting values in the database contains strings not integers. But the code that creates the table defines three columns of integer datatype. Now it is not clear what data are you storing in these columns because one of them is called `Description` hardly a number.

**EDIT** As from your comment, it seems that you have a rather old version of sqlite provider.
In this case you should build a parameter and add it to the collection.

```
sqlite_cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@p1", SqlDbType.Integer));
```

Comment: +1 for beating me to the punch AND mentioning `SqlParameters`.

Comment: @Steve You're right, they are strings, I gotta change that up thx for all your help.

Also I'm getting an error saying "Finsar.sqlite doesn't contain a definition for .addwithvalue 

So what library should I declare for that?

Comment: Without AddWithValue you should return to the standard way to construct a parameter. Updating the answer

Comment: @Steve , Ok how would I construct a parameter in standard ways? Thanks - I'm waiting for the updated answer
Nvm, just saw the update - i will try it

Comment: @Steve can you show me what you mean by build the paramater? I don't know much syntax - thx

Comment: I have used the Add method of the Parameters collection to add a new Paramater. I don't have at hand the SQLite version but every  parameter class derives from the same base class DbParameter, so you could look at the [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) because it is almost identical